# Any reason why PreparedStatement isClosed() hang?

Tags: java

I was debugging some old Java code and it seems it hangs here

```
PreparedStatement myStatement;

some code.....

try {
    if (!myStatement.isClosed()) {
        myStatement.close();
    }
}
```

Now, I can't debug this directly in Netbeans, but I can compile a new jar file with log4j statements and it seems to be stuck at the if statement.

Was using ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar Oracle driver on Oracle 11g DB.

Comment: Why are you still using Java **1.4**? And why are you using a driver intended for Oracle 10 with Oracle 12?

Comment: No resource to do upgrade/migration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are calling the `close()` method in a finalizer.
Try using this way:

```
try {
    myStatement = ...
    ...// execute or fetch...
} finally {
    if(myStatement != null)
        myStatement.close();
}
```

Calling `close()` for an already closed statement does nothing so its not a problem.
You can always remove the `isClosed()`